# Ternary operator withing a useEffect() react

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, ternary

I am trying to only fire a useEffect() hook if `user` does not equal `''` (eg. the user is logged on.

Right now I can't get it working - I'd appreciate any advice on how to combine a ternary with `useEffect()`. Thank!

```
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.loggedInUser)

  user !== ''
    ? useEffect(() => {
        let data = [user.auth0Id, wallet]
        api
          .updateUserWins(data)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            return null
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      }, [wallet])
    : console.log('No user')
``
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't conditionally call a [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). It's stated in the documentation:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

Instead you have to move your conditional operator inside the function you pass to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user !== '') {
        let data = [user.auth0Id, wallet]
        api
          .updateUserWins(data)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            return null
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          });
    }
    else {
        console.log('No user')
    }
}, [wallet, user])
```

You may of course use the conditional operator ?: instead of an `if` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

One of very important rules about hooks is that you can not put them inside any condition, because order of execution must not change during element lifecycle. This means that you must move condition inside useEffect, something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(user !== ''){ // AND HERE YOU PUT CONDITION
    let data = [user.auth0Id, wallet]
    api
      .updateUserWins(data)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        return null
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}, [wallet, user])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to trigger `useEffect` only conditionally.
Better to do your conditional checks *inside* the useEffect, and see if anything needs to change.

For example:

```js
function MyComponent({user, wallet}) {

  useEffect(() => {
     if (!user) {
       return; // Either return nothing, or a cleanup function if you have one.
     }

     let data = [user.auth0Id, wallet]
     // ...rest of your logic
  }, [wallet, user]) // add user to your dependency array

...
}
```